# Problems with the subversion http module

Tags: svn, http

The subversion HTTP module will not install correctly. So I found this on the cPanel forums:

```
./configure --with-apxs=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs --with-apr=/usr/local/apache/bin/apr-1-config --with-apr-util=/home/cpeasyapache/src/httpd-2.2.19/srclib/apr-util
make
make install
```

And I got this error:

```
------ making install in serf
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/kristoffer/subversion-1.6.0/serf'
mkdir -p /usr/local/lib /usr/local/include/serf-0
/usr/local/apache/build/libtool --silent --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libserf-0.la /usr/local/lib
libtool: install: error: cannot install `libserf-0.la' to a directory not ending in /root/lib
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/kristoffer/subversion-1.6.0/serf'
make: *** [external-install] Error 1
```

I have tried setting different install paths, include paths, etc. - nothing work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose not to bother with it and download svn for Windows, download the file, pack it, and upload it to the server.